# Excel VBA - delete duplicates and keep the latest (based on date column)

Tags: vba, excel

Can somebody help me? I don't even know how to start...
I want to make a macro that deletes duplicates (based on column A) and keep the row that has the latest Date (column P). And if all duplicates have no date in column P, just keep one and delete the other duplicates.

[image]

**The Data in the sheet starts with row 5** (not row 4 like in the picture, sorry for that). In the past I know that I had problems with deleting duplicates via macro when the table don't start with row 1 or 2.

The table normally has around ~15 columns and ~10.000 rows.

Some of the rows have date in column P and some row don't. So the macro should look if there are any duplicates (column A) and if so, check if there is a date in column P. If there are more duplicates with dates, the macro should delete all duplicates but keep the most recent.

The Code I used/edited so far:

```
Sub DelDubs_Date()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Set Rng = Range("A5:P" & LastRow)

With Rng
    .Sort key1:=Range("A5"), order1:=xlAscending, key2:=Range("P5"), order2:=xlDescending, _
        Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End With

For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(i, "A")), Cells(i, "A")) > 1 Then
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Problem: it keeps the first row, not the one with the latest date...

**TL;DR: Check for Duplicates in A, then check for dates in P, then delete all duplicates but keep the latest. And if there is no date, delete all duplicates and keep one.**

Comment: There is probably a more technical way to do it but you could format as dates and add a filter to sort by newest. Then when you remove duplicates it will remove the lower ones first.

Comment: Hi Berticus, thanks for the answer! But I want to do it with an one button solution. Greetings

Comment: BlueSector, Just record a macro that implements @BerticusMaximus's solution and attach it to a button... You can still have it your way.

Comment: I did this before thinking about making a macro. But I think the code behind a recorded macro is often really slow and not that clean. But thanks!

Comment: I don't want to steal @BerticusMaximus's solution, so I'll leave it for him to post it, but I'll tell you that a solution of sorting then removing duplicates will actually be faster than the code you currently have posted.

Comment: so I can't improve my working here via macro? I planned to make a one button solution for the whole project I've been working on. Thats just a part. I think its not a good idea if I have to do small parts by hand.

Comment: Ideally, Bluesector, what you want to do is EXACTLY break it up into small parts. You write a small `SUB` for each small part so it's compartmentalized and easily maintainable and then your one-button solution just calls all the smaller subs one by one in order... It's still a one-button solution, but it calls multiple smaller portions. Each with a specific job to perform.

Comment: Why did I think so complicated? I tried to do everything in ONE macro, because I thought it would go faster...

Answer (score 0):

Since I faced the removing duplicates bug described [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/657302-removing-duplicates-excel-bug.html) and [here](http://forum.chandoo.org/threads/how-to-remove-duplicate-from-a-integer-integer-txt-values.5470/) -faced in office 2013, the threads relate to 2010 and I won't expect they fixed it in 2016 one-. I don't rely in this function ever, instead, I coded this:

```
Sub TryMe()
    Call RealRemoveDuplicates("MySheet", Range("A1:C5"))
End Sub
Sub RealRemoveDuplicates(InSheet As String, InRange As Range)
    Call CreateSheets("DummyDuplicate")
    Sheets(InSheet).Range(InRange.Address(False, False)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range( _
            "A1"), Unique:=True
    Sheets(InSheet).Range(InRange.Address(False, False)).Clear
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets(InSheet).Range(InRange.Address(1))
    Sheets("DummyDuplicate").Delete
End Sub
Sub CreateSheets(NameSheet As String, Optional Looked_Workbook As Workbook)
Dim SheetExists As Worksheet
    If Looked_Workbook Is Nothing Then Set Looked_Workbook = ThisWorkbook '1.  If Looked_Workbook Is Nothing
    On Error GoTo ExpectedErr01CreateSheets
    Set SheetExists = Looked_Workbook.Worksheets(NameSheet)
    SheetExists.Delete
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then '2.  If Err.Number <> 0
ExpectedErr01CreateSheets:         'this means sheet didn't existed so, we are going to create it
    End If '2.  If Err.Number <> 0
        With Looked_Workbook
        .Sheets.Add After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = NameSheet
        End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the dates from text to dates and you can record a macro of this:
 1. Sort by `Conf. Date` from newest to oldest
 2. Data > `Remove Duplicates` > uncheck all but the `REF` column
 3. Sort by the `REF` column

---

I think this would be easier and more flexible wit PivotTable or PowerPivot.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would just throw all this into one Sub but you seemed to like @John Bustos solution. I tested this once and it seemed to work let me know if I missed anything.

```
Option Explicit
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Sub CallSubs()
    Call FormatDates
    Call SortSmall
    Call RemoveDups
End Sub
Sub FormatDates()

Set wbk = Workbooks("Book1.xlsm")
Set ws = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    'Find last row
    lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
        After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
        MatchCase:=False).Row
    'This will only work if Columns B through O have data
    'Turn on Autofilter
    If .AutoFilterMode = False Then
        .Cells(3, 1).AutoFilter
    End If
    .Range("P4:P" & lRow).Replace What:=".", Replacement:="/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    .Range("P4:P" & lRow).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"
End With
End Sub

Sub SortSmall()

Set wbk = Workbooks("Book1.xlsm")
Set ws = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
        After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
        MatchCase:=False).Row
    'I used the macro recorder for this and cleaned it up let me know if there is a better way
    'Sort Dates Z To A
    .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.add Key:=.Range("P3:P" & lRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With .AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End With
End Sub
Sub RemoveDups()
Set wbk = Workbooks("Book1.xlsm")
Set ws = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
        After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
        MatchCase:=False).Row
    .Range("A3:P" & lRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! Unfortunately, it doesnt work :/. It only sets the autofilter in the first row (autofilter should be set in row 4).

Comment: @Bluesector Change the code to `.Cells(4, 1).AutoFilter` from `.Cells(3, 1).AutoFilter`